# How to create a dictionary of lists from each row of a text file?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file with this data

```
1, Jane Doe, 1991
2, Sam Smith, 1982
3, John Sung, 1965
4, Tony Tembo, 1977
```

I have something like this but it only works if you have the ID and name alone

```
names = {}
with open("dict.txt") as f:
  for line in f:
      (key, val) = line.strip().split(',')
      names[int(key)] = val
```

print (d)
Can I create a dictionary from this file that would look like this:

```
{1: [Jane Doe, 1991], 2: [Sam Smith, 1982]...}
```

Comment: Post what you've tried, along with a specific question about the posted code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit more simple.

```
d = {} # this is the dictonary
file = open("data.txt") # open file
for line in file:
    s = line.split() # split line
    # get data individually
    key = s[0] 
    fullname = s[1] + ' ' + s[2]
    year = s[3]
    # append to dictionary
    d[key] = [fullname, year]
# print
print(d)
```

hope this works

Comment: `split` can take an optional argument in order to split at others characters/string different than the default space like a comma or whatever else you desire, ex: `line.split(",")`

Answer (score 2):

It's best to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) module when dealing with comma-separated data.

```py
import csv

data_file = 'test.csv'
parsed = {}

with open(data_file) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        # row is ['1', ' Jane Doe', ' 1991']

        parsed[row[0]] = row[1:]

print(parsed)
```

```
['1', ' Jane Doe', ' 1991']
['2', ' Sam Smith', ' 1982']
['3', ' John Sung', ' 1965']
['4', ' Tony Tembo', ' 1977']
{'1': [' Jane Doe', ' 1991'], '2': [' Sam Smith', ' 1982'], '3': [' John Sung', ' 1965'], '4': [' Tony Tembo', ' 1977']}
```

The `reader` returns the row contents as a list. Then, it's just a matter of storing the 1st list element as the dict key, and the rest of the list elements (`[1:]`) as the dict value.

Now, that code above reads everything as a `str`, and as you can notice includes extra spaces from the file. If you need the key and values to be of certain types (and you need the list to hold differently-typed elements), then you need to parse them separately:

```py
with open(data_file) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        # row is ['1', ' Jane Doe', ' 1991']

        key = int(row[0])
        name = row[1].strip()
        year = int(row[2])

        parsed[key] = [name, year]

print(parsed)
```

```
['1', ' Jane Doe', ' 1991']
['2', ' Sam Smith', ' 1982']
['3', ' John Sung', ' 1965']
['4', ' Tony Tembo', ' 1977']
{1: ['Jane Doe', 1991], 2: ['Sam Smith', 1982], 3: ['John Sung', 1965], 4: ['Tony Tembo', 1977]}
```

Of course, you'll have the adjust the indexing and type coercion if you have more columns with different types of data.

Taking it *much* further, I would put the code for parsing the actual data and the type coercions into a class (a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html) to be exact). This way, reading the file is kept separate from parsing the actual contents:

```py
import csv
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    index: int
    name: str
    year: int

    # This is just an example to match the sample data.
    # Add more type-checking and error-handling as necessary.
    def __post_init__(self):
        # If we didn't get an int, force it to an int
        # Will raise ValueError if int(...) fails
        if not isinstance(self.index, int):
            self.index = int(self.index)
        if not isinstance(self.year, int):
            self.year = int(self.year)

        # Clean extra spaces
        self.name = self.name.strip()


data_file = 'test.csv'
parsed = {}

with open(data_file) as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        # row is ['1', ' Jane Doe', ' 1991']

        # Unpack the row contents and pass to the Person's __init__
        # Make sure it matches the order of the dataclass fields
        person = Person(*row)

        parsed[person.index] = [person.name, person.year]

print(parsed)
```

```
['1', ' Jane Doe', ' 1991']
['2', ' Sam Smith', ' 1982']
['3', ' John Sung', ' 1965']
['4', ' Tony Tembo', ' 1977']
{'1': [' Jane Doe', ' 1991'], '2': [' Sam Smith', ' 1982'], '3': [' John Sung', ' 1965'], '4': [' Tony Tembo', ' 1977']}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the expected results by splitting the contents of the file like this:

```py
data = open("data.txt", "r").read().split("\n")
dates = {}

for i in data:
    
    org_data = i.split(", ")
    serial = org_data.pop(0)
    dates[serial] = org_data

print(dates)
```

Comment: Thanks guys, all solutions have helped a lot!